# Material-UI Autocomplete endAdornment Issue

Tags: reactjs, web, material-ui, jsx

I'm trying to use Material-UI's Autocomplete component in my project.

I haven't applied any styling to it and it's rendering a bit off.

I have two issues:

1. The highlight over the down around and clearable buttons is not a small circle as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbNV9.png).
2. The dropdown only opens when I click close to the letters E, M and P. I'm assuming this is because of
   the above.

I'm not sure why that's happening because I just copied the code from Material-UI's documentation and I'm not sure which of my styles, if any, is causing the issue. I also checked on Chrome Devtools and none of my styles are being applied.

Code Snippet:

```
const employees = [
      { name: 'John Oliver' },
      { name: 'Karen Green' },
      { name: 'Alastair Brown' },
    ];

    const employeeNames = {
      options: employees,
      getOptionLabel: (option) => option.name,
    }; 

<div className="col-lg-5">
       <FormControl className="drop-down" required>
          <Autocomplete
            {...employeeNames}
            name="employee"
            autoHighlight
            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Employee" />}
          />
          <FormHelperText>Required</FormHelperText>
        </FormControl>
    </div>
```

Could someone please tell me what the problem is?

**More Screenshots**

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

**Update**

I attempted to make a reproduceable sandbox but for some reason my code works correctly over there. No changes whatsoever. It renders how i want it to. What could be the problem then?

https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-snow-5lxy7

Comment: `col-lg-5`... are you using Bootstrap? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. If you have time, you can also try to reproduce the issue in http://codesandbox.io so the viewers can easily debug the layout.

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 yes I'm using React Bootstrap. I'll try to recreate the problem in a few mins.

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 I copy pasted the entire bit in the sandbox and there are no issues there. It renders how I want it to. I added the link to the question.

Comment: I suggest you open up dev tools and compare the styles of both your project and the codesandbox you created - specifically for the sections with the bugged adornment. currently, in your screenshot, it looks like it is wrapped in a flex container with `justify-content: space between` - but this is just my guess. In addition, check the order of importing your CSS - this could be a factor since you are using multiple UI libraries (i.e., 1 stylesheet could be overriding another). Finally, test in an incognito browser so the stylesheet is not cached

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 I checked dev tool again and all the styles are the same. Incognito shows me the same bug. However, the issue seems to be with the .MuiAutocomplete-endAdornment class overlapping with all the other classes the input is using. Added another screenshot.

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 I removed the imports of my own styles just to test and that didn't work either.

Comment: try to comment out the bootstrap css

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 That didn't work either. It worked with bootstrap in the sandbox though so I'm not sure how that's an issue?

Comment: it might have been the order, again 1 stylesheet could be overriding another - so it is always a possibility. another possibility is the package versions you are using, perhaps you are using different versions of the packages in your project vs in codesandbox. at this point i could throw all the suggestions i can but the only way to accurately debug the issue is if a reproducible example or the actual code base can be examined

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 yeah I understand. I removed all my stylesheets including bootstrap and it still has the issue. I think it has something to do with material-ui. The sandbox has the same versions I'm using locally. I'm not sure what else can be done. It's such a strange behaviour. What's the order of the css that should be implemented?

Comment: It is strange that it is working on the sandbox & not on your project. At this point you could just hack it. i.e., customize the components using `makeStyles` or on your custom stylesheet. regarding the order, I suppose material-ui should take precedence - at least for this scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with a friend of mine, he was able to find a fix for it.

Upon inspecting the code, Material-UI uses buttons to represent the dropdown arrow and clear icons. So we created a CSS class to change the width of these buttons.

You can just do something like this in CSS and put it in the Autocomplete className prop:

```
.auto-complete button {
  width: auto !important;
}
```

Although, I wish I knew why this works. Hope it helps others as well.

Answer (score 0):

The issue should be fixed in scope of https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/22166.

Personally for me, replacing `selectOnFocus` with `openOnFocus` fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know Andrii. I'll keep it in mind. Cheers.